# Is the CLR capable of static interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

And if so, why can't you do this:

```
public interface IParsable
{
    static IParsable Parse(string s);
    static bool TryParse(string s, out IParsable);
}
```

in C#?

EDIT: Or, alternatively:

```
public interface IParseable<T>
{
    static T Parse(string s);
    static bool TryParse(string s, out T);
}
```

EDIT #2:
I have learned the folly of my ways by trying to use an IParsable, as suggested by many below. The example I made follows. Of course, there is no way to resolve the call to TryParse...

```
public IParsable ReadFromKeyboard()
{
    IParsable ToReturn;
    bool FirstTry = false;
    bool Success;
    do
    {
        if (!FirstTry)
            DisplayError();
        AskForInput();

        Success = IParsable.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, out ToReturn);
        FirstTry = false;
    } while(!Success)

    return ToReturn;
}
```

Comment: How would a method look like that takes an IParsable argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the CLR doesn't have such a thing as static interfaces. I've surmised that they'd be useful for generic type constraints, but that's the *only* use I can see for them... otherwise how would you *use* `IParsable` in your example? How would you pass around the type that was able to parse it?

See [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) for more details of what I was envisaging.

Comment: They would also be useful for static factory classes.

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: But how would you *use* them? Try to work out the syntax you'd use.

Comment: The static keyword could be used on the inheritence line (ie. after the colon) and interface line (ie after the keyword interface for the definition), I would also make the restriction that an Interface has to be either all static or all non-static. Any class inheriting a static interface must implement all those static methods. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Saying this, im sure there would be other semantic and logistic issues with things like Generics that would have to be worked out, it boggles the mind, but im sure some genius at Microsoft can sort it out! :D

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: That's talking about the *declaration* part. How are you going to *use* them?

Comment: I thought I did, static interface IFoo { static void TestFoo(); }, class FooImplementer : static IFoo, static IFoo2, IFoo3 { static void TestFoo(); }. They might need to include the virtual and override keywords however. Currently C# (and im guessing the CLR) has no support for the overriding of static methods using Polymorphism, basically a type can call its static method by referencing it from its instance name. When referenced from the instance name polymorphism could be applied to the static calls.

Comment: @AaronMurgatroyd: No, that's not showing *usage* at all. It's showing how you *declare* that a class implements an interface. How do I *call* that method without an instance of the interface?

Comment: Why would you want to call a method of a staic interface, it's a static abstract implementation. You would call the implementation of the interface on a class using its static method. So I'm not sure what you are asking? In my example you would call FooImplementor.TestFoo or use and call that. You would also need to be able define strongly typed class types as well. Similar to Delphis class of keyword. This would allow you to use them, if that's what you mean. Ie, type Foo IFoo.

Comment: I'm not here to design it, thats microsofts problem, but it would be a nice to have, as Delphi 7 did back in the days.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't force a class to implement static members.

Answer (score 3):

The CLR doesn't support this.  This is by design.

It has [been suggested before](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/91089/static-interfaces) - And if you read the comments there, you'll see that there are already some type-level contracts in place in the CLR (such as constraints on generics).

However, interfaces are really not the correct level for this, since they (by design) have a specific meaning: they describe a behavior contract *for an object*.  Trying to add the ability to describe a contract for a type would be changing the meaning of interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot for a class to implement static methods. There's a simple reason for this:

An interface allows you to define behavior for an instance of an Object. Static Methods don't belong to an instance of an Object, they belong to the type. Therefore, defining static methods in an interface really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The C# language syntax hides it, but a key properly of an interface method implementation is that it is a virtual method.  It is hidden, you don't actually use the virtual (or overrides) keyword when you write the implementation method.

It has to be virtual, that's how interfaces are implemented under the hood.  When you cast an object to an interface type, the runtime generates a pointer to the virtual method table section that contains the pointers to the interface method implementations.

What follows, given that virtual methods are the polar opposite of static methods, is that an interface declaration can never contain a static method.  Static methods don't have method table entries.

Answer (score 0):

No, the CLR isn't capable of static interfaces. It would be a handy feature to have, but you instead need simulate it with either regular interfaces or reflection.

Other similar features that .NET (well, C#) doesn't have: [Haskell type classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), [F# member constraints on generic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx)